# Disabling .info logging in nLog

Tags: c#, nlog

In my .net application I am using nLog for logging ,now I want to disable .info logging (ie .error and .fatal log feature sholud be enabled) is there any option exists for that? plz help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set up the minimum log levels in the rules section of the nlog config in your app.config file. So for example, the following will configure nlog so that only warnings and above (which includes errors and fatals, but not info or trace) will be logged to a target named 'file':

```
<nlog>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: You can also explicitly set levels="Error,Fatal" instead of minlevel.

Comment: Good tip! (trying to reach minimum comment length...)